# How to force dataservice with BehaviourSubject Angular to return last value set with next()

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am writing Angular Guards form my application. After a user logs in my AuthService I change the value of a BehaviourSubject variable in my userService using the next(). In my GuardService, I want to get the latest value from the variable but I always get the initial value.

userService

```
export class UserService {

private isAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
isCurrentUserAdmin = this.isAdmin.asObservable();

changeAdminRole(isAdmin: boolean) {
    // change the BehaviourSubject value
    this.isAdmin.next(isAdmin);
  }
}
```

AdminGuard

```
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate() {
    this.userService.isCurrentUserAdmin
      .subscribe((response: boolean) => {
        console.log('working here', response);
        if(response) return true;
      });

    return false;
  }
}
```

appModule

```
app.module.ts
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'products', component: ProductsListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: 'shopping-cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent},
      {path: 'my-orders', component: MyOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: 'order-success', component: OrderSuccessComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]},
      {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
    ])
],
  providers: [AuthService, UserService, AuthGuard, AdminGuard]
```

I expect the reponse in the observable of my AdminGuard when I navigate to the route I want to protect to have the latest value set in the UserService.changeAdminRole() when called from my AuthService but I am always getting null.

Comment: i think `canActivate` is implement `canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean` like this its not answer i'm just make sure about code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return `true` from subscribe not from the guard. Your guard always returns false. [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) can return also observable which eventually resolves to boolean which perfectly fits your situation:

```
canActivate() {
  return this.userService.isCurrentUserAdmin;
}
```